# How to add a time value, in the time I have already put in the database, in the MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, time, sum, resultset

> Show, along with the title of the film and the year, what the running times of science fiction films would be like, adding 20 minutes to the runtime.

I need to make a query that returns this, and I didn't find anywhere how to add these 20 minutes, in the duration I put TIME as the data type, and when I put the data I put it like this 00:00:00. Now I don't know how to do this sum.

```
SELECT title, year, duration
FROM film
WHERE genero = "fiction" 
GROUP BY duration;
```

I know until there, the problem is the sum. Does anyone know how to do it??

Comment: What is the datatype of `duration`?

Comment: If it's `TIME` or `DATETIME`, you can use `DATE_ADD(duration, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)`

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY duration` without any aggregation functions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATE_ADD()` function to add an interval to a date or time.

```
SELECT title, year, TIME(DATE_ADD(duration, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)) AS running_time
FROM film
WHERE genero = 'fiction'
```

There's no need for `GROUP BY` since you want to show all the films. Did you mean `ORDER BY duration`?

Comment: I want to show fiction movies, I just added group by because I didn't know what to do, I'm a little confused with GROUP BY and ORDER BY too, but I'm working on it, and i'm so thankful, really, thank you, it worked!!!

Comment: `GROUP BY xxx` means that you get just one row in the results for each different value of `xxx`.